# Were there any OT prophecies that Jesus should be a wood-working carpenter

Tags: life-of-jesus

I like the [stone mason theory](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/do-we-actually-know-that-jesus-was-a-carpenter) because that would make Jesus and St. Joseph (the patron of manly men) really tough.

But, is there any significance to the traditional conception of Jesus following St. Joseph as a table and chairs sort of carpenter as opposed to a millstone and monuments sort of carpenter borne of the Old Testament prophets?

Are there any allusions to carpentry in the Old Testament?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zechariah 1:20

English: And YHVH showed me four carpenters.
LXX: καὶ ἔδειξέν μοι κύριος τέσσαρας τέκτονας

The same Greek word, τέκτων, is used in Matt. 13:55 and Mark 6:3.

The Talmud (Sukka 52b) states that the four carpenters are Messiah ben David, Messiah ben Ephraim (i.e., ben Joseph), Malki-Tzedek, and Eliyahu. But, we know that Jesus is both Messiah ben David and ben Ephraim, he is a priest after the manner of Malki-Tezedek, and he is a prophet greater than Moshe.

Comment: [חָרָשׁ](http://biblehub.com/hebrew/2796.htm) in Zechariah (translated carpenter) merely means craftsman. It is used to describe masons, engravers and other types of stoneworkers & carpenters. The same is technically true of the Greek τέκτων. So, the prophecy can be fulfilled regardless of the type of craftsman. [However, τέκτων is frequently contrasted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tekt%C5%8Dn) in Greek writings with stone-worker or mason (λιθολόγος, λαξευτής) even though it could encompass these trades and so τέκτων is most closely associated with carpentry, but doesn't exclude stoneworkers

Answer (score 4):

No. I researched exactly this when working on [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4896/do-we-actually-know-that-jesus-was-a-carpenter/4902#4902). This is not mentioned in the Old Testament.

Comment: What exactly were you looking for when researching that question?

Comment: @PeterTurner: I just typed **carpenter** and some similar terms into [BibleGateway](http://www.biblegateway.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Carpentry *is* mentioned in the Old Testament but not as a prophecy about Jesus. Carpenters are mentioned in several of the histories - unsurprisingly usually in the context of building houses and the like - and once or twice in Isaiah (depending which version you use - sometimes it is translated as the more generic "craftsman" instead of "carpenter").